Error in my reactjs project deploy in github
Error: Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).
at E:\HaitamJebari\My Projects\Project 6\RentCars\main\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\git.js:214:13
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
i try to deploy my project reactjs in my github a i have done every step but still diplay this message

main@0.1.0 deploy
gh-pages -d build

Error: Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).
at E:\HaitamJebari\My Projects\Project 6\RentCars\main\node_modules\gh-pages\lib\git.js:214:13
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
PS E:\HaitamJebari\My Projects\Project 6\RentCars\main>
